# Perform switch statement if string is found

Tags: c#

Below I've put together pseudo code of what I'm trying to do. I'm not entirely sure how to write this in C#. Is something like this possible, if so how can i do it. What i want to do is a run a function if the value returned is found.

**pseudo code**

```
string list = @"
This is a multiline statement
used for testing
"

foreach (var line in list)
{
    switch (line)
    {
        case (line.Contains("multiline")):
            Console.WriteLine("has A");
            break;
        case (line.Contains("testing")):
            Console.WriteLine("has B");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want written in your example? Both “has A” and “has B”?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not possible. Using [`switch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement you just check the value of a given object. Try using a if:

```
foreach (var line in list)
{
    if (line.Contains("multiline"))
       Console.WriteLine("has A");
    else if (line.Contains("testing"))
       Console.WriteLine("has B");     
}
```

From the MSDN docs:

> The switch statement is a control statement that selects a switch
>   section to execute from a list of candidates.

The case statement is a compile time constant.
The right use of a `switch` statement could be like this:

```
int caseSwitch = /* get a int value*/;
switch (caseSwitch)
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Default case");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is called "pattern matching". C# doesn't yet support this, though [it is being actively discussed as an addition to the next release, C# 7](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/206).

There are third party solutions that allow you to achieve what you are trying to do. My own [Succinc<T> library](https://github.com/DavidArno/SuccincT) for example, would allow you to write the code as:

```
string list = @"
This is a multiline statement
used for testing
";

foreach (var line in list)
{
    line.Match()
        .Where(l => l.contains("multiline").Do(l => Console.WriteLine("has A"))
        .Where(l => l.contains("testing").Do(l => Console.WriteLine("has B"))
        .IgnoreElse()
        .Exec();
}
```

It arguably leads to easier-to-follow, more functional, code than using a series of `if`'s, though the trade-off is then in performance.

Comment: Don't you need a `l =>` in `Do`?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, well spotted! Glad someone knows how to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't have a list you could iterate. You simply have a string. You should split your string

```
string s = @"
This is a multiline statement
used for testing
";
string[] lines = s.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Then the case statement branches according to constant case values. You cannot execute conditional expressions in the cases. Therefore you need to use a series of if-else statements

```
if (condition1) {
    ...
} else if (condition2) {
    ...
} else if (condition3) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```